# AS2 - How to fix the error "Parse Unexpected" from FlashDevelop

Tags: flash, actionscript, flashdevelop, mtasc

I'm trying to compile my classes in ActionScript2 from my project but I can not always get it when I click on the Test Project option it appears this error :

> Running C: \ Program Files (x86) \ FlashDevelop \ Tools \ fdbuild \
>   fdbuild.exe "C : \ Users \ 1 \ Documents \ 1729 \ 1729.as2proj "-ipc
>   a5248614-0afe-4b9a-87dc-1b2a271bec6c -version" 1.14 "-compiler" C: \
>   Program Files (x86) \ FlashDevelop \ Tools \ mtasc "-notrace -library
>   "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ FlashDevelop \ Library" -target ""
>   Building 1729 Src / MainMovie.as: 4: characters 0-11:
>
> Parse error `Unexpected onClipEvent`
>
> Build halted with errors (mtasc). Done (1)

How do I fix this? It happens in all my projects and classes any help? thanks

Comment: I am waiting hours and days and no one answers you are going to answer me or not? I'm wasting time here.

Comment: You're bound to answer my questions. I really need help, but no one is willing to help. I'm sad.

Comment: I think many people moved to AS3 around 2008/2009 so if you ask about AS2 in 2017, don't be surprised if it's quiet...

Comment: Since the error says : `Unexpected onClipEvent` which basically means **"Your `onClipEvent` should not be here!!"** so either you are using it wrong in your code (we can't see)... Also possible cause of error is that maybe your settings are actually for compiling AS3 code (where AS2's `onClipEvent` does not exist, so it becomes "unexpected thing" to AS3 compiler when it finds this in your code)...

Comment: I just checked and can see that `mtasc` will compile AS2 code... No idea why it thinks _"Your onClipEvent should not be here!!"_. Possibly it's put in wrong place in your code? Check that its not accidentally inside another function? or similar code mistake.

Comment: Here is the zipped file link containing the ActionScript classes decompiled with Sothink SWF Decompiler http://www103.zippyshare.com/v/u4lqJgim/file.html

Comment: Love to help you but your link expired. You used Sothink to decompile your own code and now you are wondering why it doesn't compile? I suspect that you are frustrated for not being able to compile stolen code? Write your own code and then ask us to help you and you might find more people are willing to help.